# Parametric VaR, Normality and Subadditivity

Tags: value-at-risk

Good evening; I just have a simple question about Value at Risk and the subadditivity property, and I know that it may sound silly

I got that, *in general*, VaR is not subadditive. However, if a portfolio contain elliptically distributed risk factors, then VaR will be subadditive.

What I do not understand is why an ellipticall distribution, such as the Normal distribution, *implies* subadditivity of VaR.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $X\sim N(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$ are correlated *jointly normal* random variables. [Then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Correlated_random_variables), $$X+Y\sim N(\mu_X+\mu_Y,\sigma^2_X+\sigma_Y^2+2\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y).$$

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ denote the profit of your portfolio returns (so negative values for $X,Y$ mean losses). Then, the 5% value at risk is the 0.05 quantile of the profit distribution (the minimum amount you lose in the worst five percent of cases $\Leftrightarrow$ in 95% of the cases you're sure to lose less than this value-at-risk). [Thus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_at_risk#Mathematical_definition), using the inverse function of the normal distribution (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Quantile_function)),
\begin{align*}
\text{VaR}(X,\alpha)&=-\mu_X+\sigma_X\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha),\\
\text{VaR}(Y,\alpha)&=-\mu_Y+\sigma_Y\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha), \\
\text{VaR}(X+Y,\alpha)&=-\mu_X-\mu_Y+\sqrt{\sigma^2_X+\sigma_Y^2+2\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y}\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha).
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\text{VaR}(X,\alpha) + \text{VaR}(Y,\alpha) &= -\mu_X-\mu_Y+(\sigma_X+\sigma_Y)\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha) \\
&\geq -\mu_X-\mu_Y+\sqrt{\sigma^2_X+\sigma_Y^2+2\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y}\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha) \\
&= \text{VaR}(X+Y,\alpha),
\end{align*}
because for $\rho\in(-1,1)$,
\begin{align*}
\sigma_X+\sigma_Y = \sqrt{\sigma^2_X+\sigma_Y^2+2\sigma_X\sigma_Y} \geq \sqrt{\sigma^2_X+\sigma_Y^2+2\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y}.
\end{align*}

Thus, value-at-risk (just like the standard deviation) is always sub-additive for two normally distributed loss distributions, if we assume $\alpha<0.5$, (``**benefit of diversification**''): a portfolio containing $X$ and $Y$ is less risky than the sum of the individual risks. If we assume a different distribution for $X$ and $Y$, then this result may no longer hold.

You can, of course, fiddle in some weights and consider $wX+(1-w)Y$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kevin, however, I still don't get why do we need the Normality assumption to ensure subadditivity. As far as I understand, if you calculate a VaR with non-normal distribution or non-parametric approach such as Historical/Montecarlo Simulation, you may have and may not have subadditivity in the VaR of your portfolio. However, with normal distribution, this is always the case.

Comment: @AntonioStanco For the normal distribution, we can prove that VaR is always subadditive (see edit). However, this calculation may be different (no longer hold) if we assume different distributions for $X$ and $Y$. Thus, VaR is not sub-additive all the time. It only happens to be sub-additive in the special case (example) of a normal distribution (and some others).

Comment: @AntonioStanco Is it now any clearer? You can compute VaR for any distribution (parametric or non-parametric by simulations as you suggest). The question is whether VaR is always sub-additive. It turns out it is not. Take some stock data and try it out :) You'll quickly find examples where it is violated. If we however assume portfolio returns are normally distributed, then in this very special case, VaR turns out to be always sub-additive. So normality is just an example for which we know that we get the property we want

Comment: Good morning Kevin, thanks for your help. What I don't completely get is why if the underlying distribution of your assets is Normal, then you have FOR SURE sub-additivity

Comment: @AntonioStanco Just look at the equations in my answer. For the normal distribution, VaR is proportional to the standard deviation (volatility) when we ignore the mean. The standard deviation for the normal distribution is sub-additive, because $\sigma_X,\sigma_Y>0$ and $|\rho|\leq1$. It just follows from the maths. Thus, for the normal distribution, VaR is always sub-additive.

Comment: I ve read more carefully and now I got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ir7 Thanks for the edit and clarification!

Comment: @Kevin My pleasure. Btw, I love the precision and thoroughness of your answers. [You did take the time to provide the proper link for the statement. I  just thought it would be nice to stress the assumptions that the link worked with. :) ]

Comment: @ir7 Thanks a lot for that:) It means a lot to me because I think you’re on of the best contributors here. [The clearer the answer, the better. I’m happy for anyone to improve/change any of my answers.]